# Solucionar bucle infinito en PYTHON

Tags: python, while, funcion

en esta función cree un while para que cuando se ingrese un valor distinto de 1 en la variable jugar, se pidiera nuevamente que ingrese el 1, el problema es que el bucle no acaba, porque nunca se reemplaza el valor de la variable jugar, y quería saber como solucionar este bucle infinito

```
def instrucciones(variable):
jugar=input(Presione uno para comenzar a jugar")
while jugar!="1":
print("Debe ingresar 1 para continuar")
jugar=input
```

Comment: te falta identacion.

Comment: `input` es una función. `input("Presione 1")` es una llamada a función. Lo primero retorna código ejecutable, lo segundo una cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Si es necesario que uses una funcion entonces debes seguir esta logica:
Primero inicializa la variable `seleccion_usuario` con un valor distinto al de finalizacion del bucle, por ejemplo `2`. Luego haremos un `while` que se ejecutara siempre que la variable  `seleccion_usuario` sea distinto del valor entero 1. Con esto nos aseguramos que se el contenido del `while` se ejecute la primera vez.

Por ultimo, juntamos todo en una funcion, la llamamos y damos un mensaje de finalizado. Solo te falto la identacion la cual es importante en Python.

```
# definicion de la funcion
def inicia_juego():
    seleccion_usuario = 2
    while seleccion_usuario != 1:
        seleccion_usuario = int(input('Presione uno (1) para jugar: '))

# luego llamas a tu funcion
inicia_juego()
# luego, te aseguras de dar un mensaje de finalizacion.
print('fin del juego')
```

Debes notar, que si en el `input` ingresas algun texto como `hola mundo`, el codigo va a fallar pues `int('hola mundo')` no es posible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Se muy poco de Py pero en otros lenguajes se usan llaves para delimitar los bloques de código, en Python se usan las sangrías, el código que vaya dentro de un bloque va en la misma sangría como dentro de un while o un for, o una función. Después te falta una comilla en una cadena y en el while no volves a redefinir "jugar" por lo que entra en un bucle infinito. Esto deberia funcionar:

```
def instrucciones():
    jugar = input("Presione uno para comenzar a jugar\n")
    while jugar!="1":
        jugar = input("Debe ingresar 1 para continuar\n")
    print("Ha comenzado el juego")
        
instrucciones()
```

Answer (score 0):

No veo la indentación pero suponiendo que está bien, tu error está en la línea 2. El string que tenés en el input no arranca con comillas, entonces está tomando las últimas comillas como el inicio de un string. Deberías buscar el error en los colores y las ayudas del editor de texto.
Por otro lado, desconozco si falta código o no, esa función estaría recibiendo un argumento y nunca se usa **variable**.
Y por último pero no menos importante, al final estás llamando a "input" sin sus paréntesis, es decir, ahí va **input()**, de lo contrario no estás ejecutando el método y por ende **jugar** no cambia de valor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría así:

```
while True:
    print("\r Escriba un 1 para comenzar a jugar:")
    jugar=input()
    if ('1' in jugar):  break
```